# What am I doing wrong here? Trying to call custom object trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I've written a simple trigger for a custom object. And I'm trying to trigger it through my developer console:

```
trigger Account_Custom_Obj_Trigger on Account_Custom_Obj__c (before delete, before insert, before update) {

    System.debug('Hello World!');

}
```

I'm following this simple [how to guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) which instructs me to enter the following in the Execute Anonymous Window:

```
Account_Custom_Obj__c a = new Account_Custom_Obj__c(Name='Test Trigger');
insert a;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: error image]

Comment: Some of fields are marked as required, and you have not specified them during insert of particular account

Comment: Well you changed your question after I answered it :P. Now my answer is missing your original context. And your link is using the Account object not a custom Object.

Comment: @JesseMilburn your answer was correct, thanks! Just waiting for the mandatory 10 minutes to pass before I can accept.

Comment: @Daft Can you put your error message back in so the answer has better context to the question again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign your `Account_Custom_Obj__c` to an Account.

```apex
Account_Custom_Obj__c a = new Account_Custom_Obj__c(
    Name='Test Trigger',
    DMDEV25__Account__c = 'Some Account Id'
);
```

I assume on the custom Object there is a lookup to Account that is marked required.